# Swift: how to assign an optional by reference

Tags: swift

Given the following code:

```
    class Node {
        var value: Int
        var left: Node?
        var right: Node?
        init (value: Int) {
            self.value = value
        }
    }

root = Node(value: 200)
```

Then the following code assigns a new node to root.left:

```
    var temp1 = root
    temp1!.left = Node(value: 400)
```

But the following does not assign a new node to root.right:

```
    var temp2 = root!.right
    temp2 = Node(value: 300)
```

Presumably in the last code snippet root!.right is assigned to temp2 by value, if so then is there a way of assigning it by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with optionals-- the same behavior would occur if the properties `Node.left` and `Node.right` were not optionals. Rather, this has to do with Swift class properties.

In your former example, you are pointing `temp1` to the **same class instance** that `root` points to. Thus, `root` and `temp1` are the same instance of `Node`, so when you set a property in one, it changes when you get it from the other.

In your latter example, you are getting the value of `root!.right` (which is currently nil) and setting it a new variable, `temp2`. You are creating a new class instance, so you end up with **two separate class instances**. When you assign to `root.right`, it will have no effect on `temp2` (and vice versa).

Comment: Is there a way of making temp2 a reference so its possible to iterate through data structures such as: for (var temp = root; temp != nil;  temp = value < temp!.value ? temp!.left : temp!.right)

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure why you would need a reference type for this, but try making `Node` a struct rather than a class.

Comment: Because if its a reference then wouldn't temp2 point to the original rather than it be a copy?